# Pathological behaviour when evaluating a sum

Tags: syntax, scoping

When I declare the function $f$ as follows:

```
f[n_] := Sum[x/Sum[Sqrt[y], {y, 1, x}], {x, 1, n}]/n
```

the input

```
Limit[f[n],n -> Infinity]
```

does not yield an answer, in fact the evaluation is terminated after a few seconds. If I now write

```
Limit[f[x], x -> Infinity]
```

I get an answer of $0$. Why is that, according to the manual entry of "Sum" we have

> The iteration variable i is treated as local, effectively using Block.

If it matters, I use the version 9.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware of held attributes. `Sum` uses `Block` but also has `HoldAll`, which means that nothing is evaluated until the *variable* gets a value inside it - if any at all. `Limit` does not have held attributes.

If after defining `f` you evaluate `f[n]` (assuming `n` doesn't have a value in your environment) you get a

$$\frac{\sum _{x=1}^n \frac{x}{H_x^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}}{n}$$

whereas `f[x]` (again, assuming `x` is free) gives you

$$\frac{\sum _{x=1}^x \frac{x}{H_x^{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}}}{x}$$

So, note now the different summation limits and how what used to be a *free* variable is now colliding with the bounds. That shows what `Limit` actually gets and the answer, I hope.

Comment: I understand, it still feels weird that they implemented it that way. In my opinion taking a limit of some function should not depend on how you name the variable which is considered for the limit.

Comment: When it comes to manipulating _expressions_, one needs to be aware of whether a built-in has or not hold behaviour as that affects how it works. And some _expression handling_ built-ins don't have that (notably `Integrate` and `D`), allowing you to generate a expression before handing that over to the built-in, but others do. That's the way it is.